# What is the need to state the distinctness of the unit element from the zero element?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Most of the popular Analysis textbooks state the distinctness of the unit element from the zero element. For example, consider the following two:

> there exists an element $1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ *distinct from* $0$ such that $1\cdot a=a$ and $a\cdot1=1$ for all
> $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ *(existence of a unit element)*
>
> - Introduction to Real Analysis (Robert G. Bartle and Donald R. Sherbert)

> $F$ contains an element $1\neq 0$ such that $1x = x$ for every $x\in F$
>
> - Principles of mathematical analysis (Walter Rudin)

Isn't the symbolic distinctness of a constant from another constant  sufficient for the uniqueness of the two?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: $1+1$ is symbolically distinct from $2$, yet they are equal.  No, the symbolic distinctness is not sufficient to say the numbers themselves that they represent are distinct.

Comment: Can you clarify? The quoted passages do not mention uniqueness.

Comment: No. If we let $x$ be equal to $0$, then we use two different symbols to denote the same object.

Comment: One thing this accomplishes is making the $\cdot$ operation different from the $+$ operation, since $0+a=a$ matches $1\cdot a=a$ in form.

Comment: $0 \ne 1$ is needed for non-triviality: without it we could have an ordered field consisting of a single number $0$.

Comment: It is possible in some contexts for $1$ and $0$ to be equal in the structure that you build.  You will find however that in such a scenario that $1=0$ and addition and multiplication satisfy the desired properties that our set of numbers is trivial and contains only a single element.  Such a structure is uninteresting for the most part and so when defining fields we exclude it as a possibility, allowing us to write general statements about fields without having to always tread carefully with wording to avoid issues caused by this trivial example.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, $1=0$

Let, $a\in \Bbb{R}$

$a=a\cdot 1 =a\cdot 0 =0$

i.e. $\Bbb{R}=\{0\}$

In general, $(R, +,.) $ is a ring with unity $1$ and if $1=0$ , then $R=\{0\}$.

Hence, in a ring if $1=0$ then it is useless.

Comment: I have not studied rings yet. Sorry.

Comment: @thinker then forget about rings and read the answer as giving a proof that $1\ne 0$ in the sense that if in $\mathbb{R}$ we'd have $1=0$ then $\mathbb{R}$ would have a single element and this is false.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the constants $0$ and $1$ in a particular field with the concepts of additive and multiplicative identity in fields in general.

Consider the set consisting of just one element, e.g. $\{0\}$

We define $0+0=0$ and $0*0=0$. You can verify that, without the restriction that the multiplicative identity is not the same as the additive identity, this set under these operations is a field and the constant $0$ acts as both the multiplicative identity (conceptually $1$) and the additive identity (conceptually $0$).